# How to prove the statement "If  = <sup>−1</sup>, and  is nonsingular, then det() = det()" if it is true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, theorem-provers

Statement: If  = <sup>−1</sup>, and  is nonsingular, then det() = det()

Similar Example: Suppose A and B are similar matrices. Then there exists an invertible matrix P such that B = PAP<sup>-1</sup>

solution:
det B = det(PAP<sup>-1</sup>) = (det P)(det A)(det P<sup>-1</sup>) = (det P)(det A)(det P)<sup>-1</sup> = det A

Now, how can I prove the given statement above if it is true or false by using the same logic on this similar example?

Comment: Why isn't this the exact same question?

Comment: Also, use Mathjax, not HTML.  It's made for math.  To get $A^{-1}$ it's just `$A^{-1}$`.

Comment: It is indeed *exactly the same* question, because $A,B\in M_n(K)$ are called similar, if $B=PAP^{-1}$ for some $P\in GL_n(K)$.